# How to parse python code to identify global variable uses?

Tags: python, parsing

I'm using python to parse python code.  Say the code I'm parsing is:

```
def foo():
    global x, y
    x = 1
    y = 2
    print x + y
```

I want to find all uses of the globals x and y in the code.  I have a list of the globals being used ahead of time, so there's no need to extract x and y from the globals line.  So the question is: given a known list of globals being used in some python code, e.g. ['x', 'y'] in this case, how do I parse the code to find uses of those globals?

Comment: question is somewhat vague

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use ast to parse python code

```
from __future__ import print_function
import ast

src = """def foo():
    global x, y 
    x = y = 1
    y = 2
    print x + y"""


s = ast.parse(src)

gvars = set()
for i in ast.walk(s):
    # get globals
    if isinstance(i,ast.Global):
        for j in ast.walk(i):
            gvars = gvars.union(i.names)
    #get id-s of globals
    for (field_type,value) in ast.iter_fields(i):
        if field_type == "id" and value in gvars:
            print(value , "at line", i.lineno)
```

this outputs

```
x at line 3
y at line 3
y at line 4
x at line 5
y at line 5
```

This still doesn’t work correctly with respect on scope, but still finds all instances of some id in source.

example of scope parsing issue:

```
global x,y
def foo():
    x = y = 1 
    global y
    x = y = 2
    # only global y is 2

def bar():
    #here x and y are not global
    x = y = 3

foo()
bar()
print(x,y) # runtime error. x undefined
```

we would want our code to yield only
 -  y in bar func
 -  x,y at end
but it prints all occurrence's of x,y

Comment: Thank you.  That looks like the approach I should use.  Can you elaborate on what you mean by "doesn't work correctly with respect on scope"?

Comment: @user1804375 i respond in answer

Comment: Too me it looks like it should only find 'y' in foo().  But, great answer.   Thank you.  To ask a follow on: how would one modify the ast tree so that instances of the globals are renamed, for example, so that 'x' becomes 'a' and 'y' becomes 'b' prior to compiling?

Answer (score 1):

It's about to take you quite a lot of time, since looking for variables isn't a trivial parsing or regexp job. Let's consider this example:

```
def foo():
    global x, y
    x = 1  # x is one
    y = 2
    print x + y

    def x(y):
        x print y

    class x:
        y = 'lol'
```

Here we have some situations of valid and invalid using `x` and `y`. You can try to keep it simple and write a script that will track the context of the line being parsed (whether it is function definition or class variable) and will contain all the cases of using globals you can think out.

The formal approach is to use [lexical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) and [syntax](https://www.google.com/search?q=syntax+analyzer&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) analyzers. Lexical analyzer parses the code and sends lexemes (words) to the syntax analyzer which is basically a program for determining if (and *how*) a stream of lexemes fit some [formal grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar) of a language. Speaking informally, formal grammar is a set of rules that determine how the language should look like:

```
<global_definition> ::= 'global' <variables_list>
<varirable_assignment> ::= <variable> '=' <expression>
# and so on
```

This is a ton of work, but fortunately it is done in Python standard library. As @LukaRahne mentioned, [ast](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) module would be a good start. On the other hand, if you're interested in `ast` back end (and in general how source codes are used to control a computer) I would recommend you to take a look at `compiler theory` textbooks or articles.

I apologize for the mistakes in English I've made here. I haven't mastered its *formal grammar* yet.

Answer (score -2):

This will do what you are asking:

```
vars = ['x', 'y']
with open('filename') as fin:  
    for ln in fin:
        vals = ln.split()
        for var in vars:
            if var in vals:
                print ln
```

Comment: This will also find every case where `x` and `y` are referring to local variables of the same name, so it doesn't actually solve the problem.

Comment: So you are looking for something that understands scope - if you have locals of the same name you are masking the globals, that is terrible coding, besides that i was really just trying to get questioner going since the question was vague

Comment: I wasn't the one who wrote the question, I'm just saying that it seems like one use case is that it would be able to *discover* that terrible coding.

Comment: I see your point but in this case the code isn't masking its just changing globals - which is bad

Comment: I don't think this approach works at all.  First, it relies on ln.split() which just splits based on whitespace characters.  What if the code contained the line "x=1" (no whitespace)? Then split() won't find 'x'.  Second, this approach doesn't understand the code.  What if "x" is inside a string?  What if x is an attribute of another object, i.e. "something.x"?  Those cases shouldn't be caught because they don't refer to the global x.

Comment: This was meant as a starting point your points are valid and you are asking for a much more complex solution than your question implied - as far as "understanding" the code you are also correct but that would be a more massive undertaking (ie almost an interpreter) so I think you should look at the documentation on python introspection for that level of information gathering